# Holding variables in recursion

Tags: python, recursion

I am adding individual digits in a number. I MUST do this using recursion. The problem is I can't figure out how to do this without using a holding variable that keeps track of the count. I cannot pass count to the function because that could lead to user error.

If I declare count inside the function then after each declaration the value will be re-declared and thus delete its holding value.

I can't store the value in n itself because it is an integer and not a container data type. What can I do?

```
def sumDigits(n):
    if count == 0:
        return count
    else:
        count += n%10
        sumDigits(n,count)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I cannot pass count to the function because that could lead to user
>   error.

Just set it to a default value and document that it shouldn't be used. Especially since in your example code, that's basically what you're doing. This is usually how you'd solve this kind of recursion problem. If you want to obscure it slightly, you can use `**kwargs` to hide the keyword argument to the user:

```
 def sumDigits(n, **kwargs):
     try:
         count = kwargs['count']
     except KeyError:
         count = 0
     ...
     return sumDidgets(n, count = count)
```

Note that I use `**kwargs` instead of `*args` to allow the user to pass pretty much whatever the heck they want to the function as long as it's not `count =` and have it act as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Try to *save* the result as one of the function's arguments, and change it in each recursive call of the function in such way that at some point it should reach your condition to end the recursion.

Try this one:

```
def sumDigits(n, acc = 0):
    if n == 0:
        return acc
    else:
        return sumDigits(n / 10, acc + n % 10)
```

which should be called like this:

```
sumDigits(x)
```

where `x` is the input integer number.

Comment: You can skip the need to have to specify the ``0`` by adding ``acc = 0`` to the method definition. Reduce user error (which is the OP's whole concern with passing the accumulator)

Comment: @aruisdante +1. I'm new to Python, so I hadn't realised that myself either. Thanks, I'll edit.